# How can I place a divider between those list tiles

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm new to coding and I've just started my first project, I'm just reading flutter's documentation and trying to do stuff on my own, but this one's been kinda tough, how can i place a divider between those list tiles?

I've tried some stuff like ListView.separated and similar alternatives, couldn't make it work on my code, probably cause the structure of it is all wrong somehow, any tips?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  child: Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
          currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            child: Text(
              "LPI",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 32,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          accountName: Text(
            'Lucas Pereira Issler',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 22,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            ),
          ),
          accountEmail: Text(
            'lucas.issler@ftc.edu.br',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(
            Icons.pets,
            size: 40,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
          title: Text('Adoção',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 22,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
              )),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(
            Icons.remove_red_eye,
            size: 40,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
          title: Text('Desaparecidos',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 22,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
              )),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
```

Comment: Have you tried [Divider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Divider-class.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a separate ListView.separated() for the ListTile. Checkout this [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/62812f0677b09cc152e181bbdfe982b9), hope it helps.

[image]